# gnuplot plotting using piped input

Tags: pipe, gnuplot, piping

I would like to pipe data into gnuplot and plot it without entering the gnuplot command line or providing an existing script file.  Eg a one-liner such as `cat datafile | gnuplot` and see the plot come up.  Suppose the datafile is well formatted, such as two simple columns of numerical data separated by a tab or space.

As is this would close immediately even if it would work (which it doesn't) but this can be resolved with the -persist option (abbreviated -p).

Essentially I would like the following line of code to work, or to understand why it doesn't and how to modify it to work: `echo -e "1 3\n2 4\n3 5" | gnuplot -p <<< "plot '-'"`

I can get something working using the -e option, but this seems to often break for me once I start making more complex plotting commands and I don't understand exactly what that option is doing, so I would prefer to simply write a short script file using a heredoc, as attempted above. This works: `echo -e "1 3\n2 4\n3 5" | gnuplot -p -e "plot '-'"`

Why doesn't the column data that is piped into gnuplot simply plot, even when using the `plot '-'` syntax to request that plot take the data in from stdin?

Comment: The `-e` tells gnuplot to execute the following code. As simple as this. I don't understand what your actual problem is: you have a working snippet.

Comment: I don't want to depend on the -e option, that's the idea.  I'd rather just use an actual script file but in the form of a heredocument.  The code should then execute from the heredoc gnuplot commands, rather than from -e;  but this doesn't work.  This is what I would like to understand and make work.  Thanks

Comment: Rather actually the issue is that I am trying to understand how to pipe data in when feeding a script as a heredoc.  Eg the following works `gnuplot -p <<< script` but when also piping in data like the following it fails `cat data | gnuplot -p <<< script`.  Is there a way to use a heredoc script and pipe data at the same time?

Comment: create an alias or a function, something like `alias gp="gnuplot -p -e \"plot '-'\" "`. Then you can use it as `cat 'data.dat' | gp`. Alternatively, you can create a gnuplot script and place it in `/usr/bin/` or `/usr/local/bin/`

Answer (score 0):

You want to pipe 2 different streams to `gnuplot`: data and plot commands. Gnuplot takes just one. Then why not simply concatenate the plot commands and data?

```
cat > file << .
plot '-' using (\$1):(\$2)
1 2
2 3
3 4
e
.
```

and then `cat file | gnuplot -p`.

Remember to escape the `$` characters if they are gnuplot variables and not shell variables.